# How to install Visual Studio 2017 and components to another drive?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I have a small SSD drive with only 2-3 GB free space. I need the .NET desktop and C++ desktop workloads. I tried creating offline installer, that went fine and I tried -installPath option, but it only affects the studio itself and some other components but not the Windows SDK and .NET SDK, those get installed to system drive.

I did install Windows SDK and .NET SDK's to to different drive but I had to use standalone installers for each. I was wondering if it is possible to accomplish with the installer that VS 2017 comes with.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Before installing VS2017, I copied the "C:/Program Files[ (x86)]/Microsoft SDKs" folders (as well as a few other bloaty msvc folders) from my C drive to a larger drive and used mklink (mklink /D <link in C> <target elsewhere>) to make it appear like the folders are still in the C drive. Not only did that free a bunch of gigs from my C drive, but it also caused the VS2017 installer to install less to the C drive (as the files it installed through the link ended up in the large drive instead). No problems so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the VS installer only allows you to specify where packages for that instance of VS are installed (i.e. anything that goes into the folder that you *do* get to choose).  It does not currently allow you to specify where other global packages are installed.

Comment: That's awful. So if you have a small SSD boot drive your stuffed, nice work MS!

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49055/vs2015-vs2017-ignore-path-selection-during-install.html

Answer (score 0):

Someone proposed a hack in this thread

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e7160ef-505e-4c48-a1aa-78e778c13ee0/install-visual-studio-2017-in-d-drive?forum=vssetup

> I was able to do this using a Junction.  First, I went to the
>   installer and found where the files on C would be installed, even when
>   another drive is selected:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared
>
> Then, I created a new folder on H, a much larger SSD. I called it
>   VSSHARED.
>
> Then I opened cmd.exe as an administrator and ran:
>
> mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared"
>   "H\VSSHARED"
>
> The installer, once run, placed all of the shared information into H
>   because it thought it was a folder in C.

And right below there's a similar reply:

> enter admin privileges in cmd.exe and enter the lines below
>
> mklink / J "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \
>   Shared" "F: \ msvs2017 \ shared" mklink / J "C: \ Program Files (x86)
>   \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ Installer" F: \ msvs2017 \ Installer "
>   mklink / J "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2017
>   \ Enterprise" "F: \ msvs2017 \ Enterprise"
>
> change "F: \ msvs2017" to the mklink target lines by the drive and
>   directory where it will be installed.
>
> have Fun

I ignore if there are any downsides to doing this.

Edit: I just noticed someone commented this solution in the comment section. Well, I think it doesn't hurt to have it as an answer.

Comment: I had numerous occasions where windows updates would fail because I used junctions to free up some space on the ssd, so if you want to have it as an answer I suppose you should mention possible issues it may cause.