# How to choose VS 2017 workloads install path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a 120Gb SSD (C:) and a 1Tb HD (D:). Because of that I installed VS 2017 on D, but as I install workloads, it goes to C, and I don't have the space for that. I researched and found nothing, so here am I. 
 Someone knows how to change the install location of these workflows?

Edit: I already changed the Android SDK folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Visual Studio 2017 and components to another drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284829/how-to-install-visual-studio-2017-and-components-to-another-drive)